# Running Phantomjs Without Selenium

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, automated-tests

Is there any way to run [**PhantomJS**](http://phantomjs.org/) without [**Selenium**](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)?

Comment: Submitted a formal answer but if there is more than that that you want to know, please edit question and tell why and what do you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS is a proper standalone program that you can build yourself or get prebuilt binaries of.

Just download the binary corresponding to your operating system from [official website](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and launch it from command-line:

Linux, MacOS:
`./phantomjs script.js`

Windows:
`phantomjs.exe script.js`